# Could Cassini crash land on Mercury?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, end-of-life, gravity-assist, cassini

I saw a [news article](http://www.space.com/3087-death-spacecraft-unknown-fate-cassini.html) once that discussed having Cassini use gravity assists to crash land on Mercury to end it's life. Is this even possible, and is there a chance that this could actually happen? Or is it just a space.com crazy article with no basis in reality?

Just to give a few relevant quotes:

> Should Cassini be directed back toward the inner solar system it is
>   likely her final port of call would be Jupiter, Mitchell explained,
>   "One possibility is to escape Saturn and then most likely put the
>   spacecraft on an impacting trajectory with Jupiter. This appears to be
>   feasible, but the flight times get to be rather long."
>
> Cassini's leisurely final journey need not end at Jupiter; rather the
>   giant planet's gravity could fling Cassini into position for an impact
>   on Mercury. Such an impact would provide valuable data on the
>   composition of Mercury's surface and could feasibly occur around 2021
>   to be observed by the BepiColombo spacecraft.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini%E2%80%93Huygens)

> Some of the options examined include collision with Saturn atmosphere, icy satellite, or rings; another is departure from Saturn orbit to Jupiter, Uranus, Neptune, or a Centaur. Other options include leaving it in certain stable orbits around Saturn, or departure to a heliocentric orbit. Each plan requires certain amounts of time and changes in velocity.Another possibility was aerobraking into orbit around Titan.

These images gives us the **clear idea of the possible end-life of cassini**.

[image]

[image]

And also the delta v required to reach mercury from Saturn is very large and cannot be obtained by gravity assist

so getting cassini to mercury and crashing it , is **time consuming** but still possible by gravity assist by a Jupiter Venus or Jupiter Venus earth flyby

Comment: If you can get it aimed for Jupiter, you can slingshot from Jupiter towards the inner worlds. In fact, if you have enough ∆V (either in reaction mass alone or reaction mass plus slingshots) to get to jupiter, you have enough to put it inbound for any of the inner worlds you choose.